# Transition over other elements CSS

Tags: css

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gcats/e8Q3y/)

When clicking in a square I needed to make the others disappear (so there's no scroll bar) using the same transition.
How to do it?

```
.block {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; /*animation*/
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the fastest way you can add to body or parent where squares are class named 'opened' when you click and remove this class when you click again square. Here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Q3y/1/)

```
$(".block").click(function(i, o){
    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
        $(this).removeClass("open");
        $('body').removeClass("opened");
    } else { 
        $(this).addClass("open");   
        $('body').addClass("opened");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to add a `close` class to the sibling elements.

[**jsFiddle exmaple**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/jMX6L/)

```
.close {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0%;
    margin:0;
}
```

I simplified your jQuery by using `toggleClass`:

```
$(".block").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open').siblings().toggleClass('close');
});
```

Comment: I wanted it to dissapear after the animation was done, as if the screen edges were eating the smaller squares.